# Find Maximum Value Possible By Addition and Subtraction From Array Values Without Overlapping

Tags: algorithm, sorting

### Inputs

Given an `array`, a `maximum` value and a `current` value.

### Goal

For each `i` in `array[i]`, `array[i]` must add or subtract from `current`. I can't exactly find out when I should add or subtract to get the following `output`.

### Output

The highest value possible that current can get without getting higher than `maximum` or less than 0. If not possible return -1.

### Question

I came up with the following snippet but it's not correct. If I calculate every possible answer and then find the maximum one the complexity becomes higher than O(n). How can I know when to subtract or add?

```js
function calcMax(array, max, current) {
  let output = current;
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (output + array[i] <= max) {
      output += array[i];
    } else {
      output -= array[i];
    }
    return output < 0 ? -1 : output;
  }
}

console.log(calcMax([5, 3, 7], 16, 5))
```

### Examples

Inputs: ([15, 2, 9, 10], 20, 8).
Correct output: **-1**

Inputs: ([5, 3, 7], 10, 5).
Correct output: **10** (5 - 5 + 3 + 7)

Inputs: ([5, 3, 7], 16, 5).
Correct output: **14** (5 + 5 - 3 + 7)

Comment: Sounds like you need to assign `+` or `-` to every array element so that the resulting sum (together with `current`) doesn't exceed the bounds. Are you sure this is an O(n) problem? (That is, are you sure there exists an O(n) algorithm to solve the problem?) To be O(n), you would need to find a rule for making the assignments sequentially with at most a fixed look-ahead horizon.

Comment: @TedHopp I'm actually not sure if there exists an O(n) solution.

Comment: How long is the input? How big can maximum be?

Comment: You can solve the problem in O(mn) where `m` is the maximum and `n` is the number of elements in the array. So if you treat `m` as a constant, then there *is* an O(n) algorithm.

Comment: @juvian max of array length = 50. max of array values = 1000.

Comment: Why is `15 - 8 + 2 + 9 - 10 = 8` not an answer for the input `([15, 2, 9, 10], 20, 8)` ?

Comment: @SomeDude As it starts with 8 and array[0] is 15 both addition and subtraction fails to stay inside the bounds. 8 + 15 > 20 and 8 - 15 < 0.

Comment: Ok, I thought you need to check A[i] - current. Anyway I think the solution I posted should take care of that because the queue becomes empty and tree never gets past the root, ans will be -1.

Comment: This is a prominent version of the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), and it can be solved in pseudo-polynomial time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to me is to traverse two paths - add, subtract.
If consider add, subtract as 2 different paths, it would form a binary tree. For example the array `[5, 3, 7]` and `max = 16`, `curr = 5` form a binary tree of :

```
                                    5

                              0           10

                                3       7        13

                                 10   0  14   6
```

where the left child is a subtract and right child is an add. Current value is the node value and element to be added is `A[i]`

Observe that binary tree is not full because it is constrained by [0, max].
You see that it doesn't have nodes which are less than 0 and greater than maximum.

You could implement a queue based approach to traverse the tree and find the maximum value at last level after all array elements are processed.

Pseudocode would be:

```
Queue q = new Queue
q.add( current )
int i = 0 //index into array
ans = -1
while ( !q.isEmpty() AND i < A.length )
   int qsize = q.size()
   for ( int j = 0; j < qsize; j++ )
      int currVal = q.poll()
      int addValue = currVal + A[i]
      int subValue = currVal - A[i]
      if ( subValue >= 0 && subValue <= max )
         q.add( subValue );
      if ( addValue >= 0 && addValue <= max )
         q.add( addValue );

   i++

 //now we processed all array elements, now check max value obtained in the last level if any.
 while ( !q.isEmpty ) 
     ans = Math.max( ans, q.poll() )  

 return ans == current ? -1 : ans;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm gonna check it.

Comment: Do you think if my answer is more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a recursive solution. <strike>I think it's O(n).</strike>

```js
const max = 50;
const current = 20
const array = [20, 30, 4, 14, 16];
let answer = -1;


function calcMax(i, value) {
    
    // Checking the bounds
    if (i === array.length)         {return value}
    if (value > max || value < 0)   {return -1}
    
    
    // With each index compare it with final answer
    let r = 0;
    if (value + array[i] <= max) {
        r = calcMax(i + 1, value + array[i]);
        if (r > answer) {
            answer = r;
        }
    }
    if (value - array[i] >= 0) {
        r = calcMax(i + 1, value - array[i]);
        if (r > answer) {
            answer = r;
        }
    }
    return r;
}


calcMax(0, current);
console.log(answer);
```

Comment: Sure it's O(2^n): if e.g. `current = n`, the array is n `1`s, and `max = 2*n`, this makes two calls to `calcMax` from each one for the previous `i`. So it's one starting call, 2 calls for `i = 1`, 4 calls for `i = 2`, ..., `2^{n-1}` calls for `i = n-1`.